# How to add icon in a cell before text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add to the table cell a `Font-Awesome` icon. But I need to insert it before this cell text. How to do it via `JavaScript` or `Jquery`?

That's my code:

```
var song_nameL = tr.insertCell(0);
song_nameL.innerHTML = songName;
var fa_times = song_nameL.appendChild(document.createElement("i"));
fa_times.className = "fa fa-times";
```

[image]

As you see, it appears after the text. And if I put `song_nameL.innerHTML = songName;` to the end of this code, there will be no icon.
I tried to increase `zIndex` of icon, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML code for the `<i>` element should be in front of / before the song name, so just do:

`song_nameL.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>' + song_nameL;`

Comment: Thanks, it helped! I will accept your answer after several minutes

Comment: You're welcome (Btw, z-indexing has to do with the (missing) 3rd dimension on your screen, so higher z-index means draw on top of lower z-index)

Answer (score 3):

You have to `prepend` that `<i>` element,

```
var fa_times = song_nameL.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',"<i class='fa fa-times'></i>"));
```

by using [`.insertAdjacentHTML("position", "htmlString");`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Answer (score 1):

if you need the object you could use:

```
var fa_times = document.createElement("i");
fa_times.className = "fa fa-times";
song_nameL.insertBefore(fa_times, song_nameL.childNodes[0]);
```